# Plugin handshake timeout for $myHttpURLforOrionPlugin

Tags: php, plugins, ibm-cloud, code-assist, eclipse-orion

I followed these steps from the guide found at http://planetorion.org/news/2012/01/writing-a-content-assist-plugin-for-orion/ and modified the Ruby plugin to handle keyword assist for some PHP keywords. I copied the git repo and have an almost identic repo at https://github.com/oscaralmgrenibm/orion.php.git

Now I've also installed and uploaded my files to a placeholder app running at http://oscarorionplugin.mybluemix.net/phpEditor.html. Using that link in my DevOps Services Eclipse Orion WebIDE, I get the following error:

Plugin handshake timeout for: http://oscarorionplugin.mybluemix.net/phpEditor.html

Anyone had similar issues and figured out what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

**Current Solution**

1. Create a new *public project* on IBM DevOps Services, init git repo and put all files related to the plugin there.
2. Browse project and open up *yourPlugin.html* in web editor (Edit code)
3. Right-click file and choose View in Browser
4. Copy URL from browser
5. Paste in Install Plugin button URL

It seems to be related to HTTPS and I have no further details at this moment on how to do it in a simpler way.